# 404 error constantly in Codeigniter project

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I know this question has been asked before but I've tried around 10-15 solutions on the web and on here but nothing seems to work.

I've tried both on godaddy and linode servers and both "snap" loads the 404 (CSS generated) page in virtually all pages.

I've tried changing the apache file to "override all" to no avail.

I've tried messing with htaccess to no avail, I just turned it off for now.

Code was working on local pc but just shows nothing but 404 on live servers.

Linode being served off of http://45.33.92.123

Controller name is Login_C

Comment: Please add your .htaccess file to the question. Also is $route properly setup?

Comment: problem was solved I will post my findings shortly.